# How to generate Aggregate report in Jmeter after maven execution?

Tags: maven, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running my JMeter scripts from Jenkins via jmeter-maven-plugin. The jtl file gets generated successfully. But not able to automatically generate the Aggregate report from the jtl file. Looks like maven does not create the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool even after adding the below dependency in pom.xml

`<jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.2</jmeterExtension>`

Please help on how to configure JMeter to create the Aggregate report, so that I can archive the report in Jenkins and make it available for download.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all your syntax is not correct, [it should be something like](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath):

   ```
   <jmeterExtensions>
       <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.2<</artifact>
   </jmeterExtensions>
   ```
2. Second, JMeter Maven Plugin provides [possibility](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Generating-Reports) to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) given you have the following line in your POM file:

   ```
   <generateReports>true</generateReports>
   ```

   and the dashboard has its own version of the Aggregate Report table (plus APDEX plus interactive zoomable charts)

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)